# Is Tare weight dropped from Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, packaging

**Is Packaging weight (weight of the box or packaging) dropped in Magento 2.4?**

I wanted to configure Packaging weight, to include in the shipping cost or in product cost.
Earlier Tare weight doc was available at this https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/magento-shipping-packaging.html

[image]

However, it redirects to https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/delivery.html
Here I cannot find details regarding Tare Weight.

Answer (score 1):

**Tare weight** was showing from the Temando_Shipping module.

**Temando_Shipping** module already removed from Magento 2.3.5 and so in Magento 2.4 it won't be there.

> Due to the impending shutdown of Temando, the provider of the
> technology behind Magento Shipping, it is no longer possible to create
> a new Magento Shipping account. Support for current Magento Shipping
> deployments for all existing customers will continue.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/shipping/magento-shipping-packaging.html

https://magento.com/shipping

Comment: oh. So, then is there any alternative to manage Packaging weight?

Comment: if you are already using temando in existing website, then temando and magento will support. I could not see any alternative solution ,, just check with ShipperHQ

Comment: ShipperHQ, seems be an alternative to Temando, has too many features (i'm ok with Table Rate shipping)....... I also searched some extensions, but they were based on Dimensional logic, which I dont want.......Only looking for Tare weight feature, i.e, adding weight of Box depending on total weight of products.